# Order of execution in Golang involving defer and goroutine

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I have an easy-to-follow logging situation that seems to be occurring in the wrong order.

[image: Here are two events related by a transaction ID.]

As you can see, the start time of the first row occurs before the start time of the second row.  Yet the execution of the second row fully encapsulates the execution represented by the first row, so this doesn't seem possible.

This code executes first:

```
    defer func(begin time.Time) {
        p.logger.InfoV(ctx, "Properties Listsearch "+method,
            zap.Any("searchRequest", ctx.Request.URL.Query()),
            zap.Float64("elapsed", time.Now().Sub(begin).Round(time.Millisecond).Seconds()),
        )
    }(time.Now())
```

Then, about 40 lines later, a function is called which contains this code:

```
    go func() {
        companyFacetsStartTime := time.Now()
        // actual work occurs here
        p.logger.DebugV(ctx, "company facets query complete", zap.Float64("elapsed", time.Now().Sub(companyFacetsStartTime).Round(time.Millisecond).Seconds()))
    }()
```

I am looking at logs that contain the same transactionID's, so these two calls have to be related.

It doesn't seem possible for row 1's Start to come before row 2's Start.  Is there something about the way the defer in the first code block is executed that makes its time.Now() execute later than the time.Now() in the second code block?  If not, is there any other explanation?

Comment: goroutines start execution at some point after they're instantiated.  Almost never is this immediately; generally the caller of `go` will continue to execute for sometime.    `defer` will always run at the return of the function in which it was instantiated.  So depending on what happens in that function, it's entirely forseeable that the `defer` would happen before, during, or after the `go`.  But if the containing function does no blocking operation, and returns quickly, it becomes even more likely that the `defer` will happen before the `go` function gets scheduled.

Comment: What @erik258 said - and never assume the order of execution of any two goroutine unless you have explicit flow controls in place (`sync.Mutex`, `sync.WaitGroup`, channels etc.)

Comment: I understand that you can't be sure about the execution of the deferred func, but I am referring to the value of the `begin` parameter.  Shouldn't `time.Now()` in the parameter list be set when the `defer` is executed (not when the function is executed)?  So how can that `time.Now()` be greater than the `time.Now()` in the second code block, which comes later?

Comment: @greymatter: the timestamps in the logs can't come from the defer argument, because `begin` is only used to calculate the duration.

Comment: @JimB: your comment made me realize the flaw in my logic.  I am copying the Start time from the logging timestamp.  That Start label is very misleading, because it is not when the operation started.  I apologize for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

From your comment `Shouldn't time.Now() in the parameter list be set when the defer is executed` - the answers is no.

`defer` function parameters are evaluated when the `defer` statement is encountered - even though the `defer` function won't be executed until the container function's completion.

Quoting from the [go language spec](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Defer_statements)

> Each time a "defer" statement executes, the function value and
> parameters to the call are evaluated as usual and saved anew but the
> actual function is not invoked.

so in your example:

```
defer func(begin time.Time) {
    p.logger.InfoV(ctx, "Properties Listsearch "+method,
        zap.Any("searchRequest", ctx.Request.URL.Query()),
        zap.Float64("elapsed", time.Now().Sub(begin).Round(time.Millisecond).Seconds()),
    )
}(time.Now()) // time.Now() is collected when this defer statement is processed ... 
// ... even though execution is later.
```

Since you want to capture elapsed time of the container function, this is actually the *correct* `time.Now()` you want to capture.

If you evaluated `begin` from within the `defer` code, the duration reported would simply just record the elapsed time to evaluate the zap log's parameters.

Comment: I confused things here by using the wrong terminology.  I said "when the defer is executed" which I think is more properly stated as "when the defer is evaluated."  I meant the same thing, but I didn't say it correctly.  As it turns out, my actual problem came from mislabeling the logging timestamp as the Start time, which is where my problem came from in the first place.  Thanks for your answer.  Sorry to have wasted your time.

Answer (score -1):

I confused the situation by copying the logging timestamp and labeling it as Start time.  That led to my misinterpreting the order of things, which is why I posted this question.

This whole question is a confusing mess that probably should be deleted, rather than waste other peoples' time on SO.  Is that the right thing to do?

I apologize for this whole mess.